# How to enable sort by columns,search and filter in gallery of power apps

Tags: powerapps

```
SortByColumns(
    Search(sourx,'txtinput1'.Text,"Identify"),
    Filter(sourx,Team="kiwi"),
    "order_No",
    Descending)
```

I had tried with above formula but its showing error.

Comment: Please add some context. Where are you applying your formula, what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation for the SortByColumns function](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-sort), you will see that the first parameter is the table to be sorted, and the second parameter is the column on which you want to sort. In your expression, you have a table (the result of Search) in the first parameter, and *another table* (the result of Filter) in the second parameter - that is why you see the error.

If you want to use both Search and Filter in the same table, you can *compose* them, by feeding the result of one of those functions to the other, similar to the example below:

```
SortByColumns(
    Search(
        Filter(sourx, Team = "kiwi"), // the result of Filter will be Search'ed
        'txtinput1'.Text,
        "Identify"),
    "order_No",
    SortOrder.Descending)
```

Comment: Thanks bro its working